# Ajuda com IF e ELSE em JS

Tags: html, jquery

Antes de tudo preciso dizer que estou começando agora a trabalhar com `JavaScript`, me desculpem se eu errar o nome de algo ou falar alguma bobeira, vamos lá.

O meu objetivo é ter um modal com etapas, com botões de **Continuar** e **Voltar**, eu achei uma referência em que o usuário mostra isso perfeitamente, porém, só com o botão para continuar.

Então, criei e comecei a tentar fazer o botão **Voltar** funcionar, mas, sem sucesso.
Quando eu volto para *(info_principais)* e depois clico em **Continuar**, é exibido todas as etapas juntas.

```js
// MODAL COM ETAPAS (NEXT or LAST)
$(() => {
  var verifica_etapas = false;          
  $('.color').hide();
  $('.checks').hide();
  $('.modal-footer-etapas').hide();
    
  // CONTINUAR ETAPAS
  $('.next_modal').on('click', () => {
    verifica_etapas = !verifica_etapas;        
        
    if(verifica_etapas) {
      $('.color').show();
      $('.info_principais').hide();
    } else {
      $('.checks').show();
      $('.color').hide();
      $('.modal-footer-etapas').show();
    }
  })
    
  // VOLTAR ETAPAS
  $('.last_modal').on('click', () => {
    verifica_etapas = !verifica_etapas;        
        
    if(verifica_etapas) {
      $('.info_principais').show();
      $('.color').hide();
    } 
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="add_produtos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content animated flipInX">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST">
          <div class="info_principais">
            <h3> Etapa informações principais...</h3>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-3 next_modal">CONTINUAR</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mt-3" data-dismiss="modal">FECHAR</button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group color">
            <h3> Etapa de cores...</h3>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-3 next_modal">CONTINUAR</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mt-3 last_modal">VOLTAR</button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group checks">
            <h3> Etapa de checks...</h3>
            <!--Botão de enviar aparece aqui...-->
          </div>
          <!-- BOTÃO DE ENVIAR! -->
          <div class="modal-footer-etapas">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3"> CADASTRAR</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mt-3 last_modal">VOLTAR</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Referência: [Clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445324/preenchimento-din%C3%A2mico-de-formul%C3%A1rio-dentro-de-div-modal)

Comment: https://codepen.io/adambui/pen/KmJwdw

Comment: seu código não está funcional

Comment: obrigado @LeoCaracciolo, com este exemplo, consegui finalizar!